# Jenkins is running as a docker image in a kubernetes cluster and won't come up due to plugin version incompatibility

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

We are running Jenkins as a docker image in a kubernetes cluster. However it does not come up any more because of some plugin version incompatibility.
How can we upgrade the plugins, or disable them to bring up Jenkins?

Note that because Jenkins is not up, we cannot upgrade / disable plugins with the Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what plugins are causing the issue, you can [use the Jenkins CLI](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#install-with-cli) to remove or downgrade those plugins.  For instance:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ install-plugin SOURCE ... [-deploy] [-name VAL] [-restart]

Installs a plugin either from a file, an URL, or from update center.

 SOURCE    : If this points to a local file, that file will be installed. If
             this is an URL, Jenkins downloads the URL and installs that as a
             plugin.Otherwise the name is assumed to be the short name of the
             plugin in the existing update center (like "findbugs"),and the
             plugin will be installed from the update center.
 -deploy   : Deploy plugins right away without postponing them until the reboot.
 -name VAL : If specified, the plugin will be installed as this short name
             (whereas normally the name is inferred from the source name
             automatically).
 -restart  : Restart Jenkins upon successful installation.
```

I believe you can also just drop an .hpi file into a plugins directory in your Jenkins installation, but I've never needed to resort to this solution before, so I can't say how well it works.